mui toolpad with custom router (redwoodjs)
I am trying to use mui toolpad with a custom router, namely redwoodjs's router.  I can get the routes working, but the "active" route/menu item doesn't stay selected after navigating.  So assuming that part of the toolpad's router is not directly compatible.  Does anyone have an example of using mui toolpad with redwoodjs router?  Or an example of toolpad with just a custom router that I might be able to wire up to redwood? thanks
https://mui.com/toolpad/
https://docs.redwoodjs.com/docs/router/
